# Php while loop to echo 24 hours from 01:00:00 to 23:00:00 using date and mktime

Tags: php, time, mktime

I need a php script which shows all the hours from 01:00:00 to 24:00:00.
So far i have done this: (this code is in a while loop)

```
  $hour++;
  $hour_after_midnight = date('G:i:s',mktime(1,0,0,1,1,2011));
  $next_hour = date($this_hour,strtotime('+1 hour'));
  echo $next_hour;
```

but the above code returns:

> 1:00:00 x24times

I think that the date function i am using is wrong.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not `for ($i=1; $i<=24; $i++) echo $i < 10 ? "0$i:00:00" : "$i:00:00";`?

Comment: Please note that you've managed to omit vital parts of your code, such as the value of `$this_hour`, while you include variables that are not used anywhere we can see, such as `$hour` or `$hour_after_midnight`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$hour = 0;
while($hour++ < 24)
{
    $timetoprint = date('G:i:s',mktime($hour,0,0,1,1,2011));
    echo $timetoprint;
}
?>
```

That'll do it the way you are trying to do it? I assume you need the date variable to be in that form for a reason. Otherwise the comments are the way to go.

Comment: Accepting the response would be the "correct"/good thing to do here =D.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$this_hour = $next_hour;
```

(after `echo`), looks like you've forgotten to update the time offset for the *next* time offset in your loop.

You might wanted to do that with `$hour++` but that variable is not used in the code next to this single statement.

But this answer is maybe as wrong as most of your code *looks* wrong (with the full respect), if you better describe your actual problem you have while coding, users here on SO can give better answers, see as well the answer by *Edgar Velasquez Lim* which has some other code example.

For example do you have problems to understand the `date`, `mktime` or `strtotime` function on which problems in concrete?

Are you having problems to understand what happens with variables while you're manipulating them in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$iTimestamp = mktime(1,0,0,1,1,2011);
for ($i = 1; $i < 24; $i++) {
    echo date('H:i:s', $iTimestamp) . "\n<br />";
    $iTimestamp += 3600;
}
```